# Trying to add a player dash component to my Unity C# game -- Won't dash when standing still

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've been working on creating smooth movement in a 2D Unity game and I'm currently working with a dash feature. The player will dash while moving in the right or left direction, but when trying to dash when the player is still, nothing happens.

I am new to game developing, the C# language, and stack overflow, any feedback is appreciated. Thank you

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;


    private float horizontal;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;
    [SerializeField] private float MoveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpForce = 5f;


    private bool CanDash = true;
    private bool IsDashing;
    [SerializeField] private float DashPower = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float DashCooldown = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float DashTime = 0.4f;



    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        CanDash = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpForce);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && CanDash)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (IsDashing)
        {
            return;
        }

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * MoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        CanDash = false;
        IsDashing = true;
        float OriginalGravity = rb.gravityScale;
        rb.gravityScale = 0f;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * DashPower, 0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashTime);
        rb.gravityScale = OriginalGravity;
        IsDashing = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashCooldown);
        CanDash = true;
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well if he was still horizontal is 0 and anything *0 is 0 so no. He wont move

Comment: Thanks, do you have any ideas on how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

As user BugFinder was trying to make clear in his comment, your issue is that the variable "horizontal" is set to zero whenever the player is still.
The line:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * DashPower, 0f);
```

Uses horizontal which is always 0 when you are not moving. This is because of your update function which has:

```
horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

When there is not input, GetAxisRaw is probably returning 0. I think what you are trying to do is store the direction you are facing. I'd make a different variable "direction" like follows:

```
horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")
if(horizontal != 0) direction = horizontal;
```

In the future, I'd recommending practicing a bit of debugging. You should have been able to work this out by using `Debug.log(horizontal);` which would log 0. Another note, if you keep using Unity for a while, I'd recommend looking at c# naming conventions. Private variables should have lowerCamelCase or _lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful